# Swift: check for successful HTTP status code

Tags: swift, http

I'd like to see if an HTTPURLResponse statusCode begins with 2 to indicate success. Does it make more sense to see if it falls between 200 and 299, inclusive? Or does Swift have a builtin function to see if an HTTP status code represents success?

That is, given,

```
var statusCode: Int = ..
```

which, if any, of the following expressions would be preferred?

```
let success = String(statusCode).prefix(1) == "2"
```

```
let success = statusCode < 300 && statusCode >= 200
```

The relevant documentation reads,

```
The first digit of the Status-Code defines the class of response. The
   last two digits do not have any categorization role. There are 5
   values for the first digit:

      - 1xx: Informational - Request received, continuing process

      - 2xx: Success - The action was successfully received,
        understood, and accepted

      - 3xx: Redirection - Further action must be taken in order to
        complete the request

      - 4xx: Client Error - The request contains bad syntax or cannot
        be fulfilled

      - 5xx: Server Error - The server failed to fulfill an apparently
        valid request
```

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: Use a switch statement with a range 200...299, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that anything between 200 and 299 (inclusive) means success.

However, it's not a complete picture. A 3XX response might mean that you don't know if the request is successful *yet*, and you need to follow the redirect to find out what the real status was.

A 303 redirect can lead to a URI that returns a 404, or a 200 OK.